# Change logfile path with batch file

Tags: batch-file, unity-game-engine

From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) of Unity you can change the logfile path by adding

```
-logFile <pathname>
```

I tried doing that with a batch file:

```
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0 
Game.exe -batchmode -logFile<D:\Test\>
```

This just starts the Windows Command Prompt and nothing happens. Also i don't know how to change the `<pathname>` of the `-logfile` so that it uses the path of the batch file.

Comment: Are you aware that you should be using, `D:\Test` not `<D:\Test\>`?

Comment: You might need to put `unity.exe` before the code. Sounds like it cannot find the command.

Comment: Just to be sure: you are running `Game.exe` but those command line arguments from the documentation apply **only** to the Unity editor (unity.exe) itself, not any builded application.

Comment: @Compo didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @JohnKens thats not working either.

Comment: @derHugo thats wrong see: "You can run the Editor and built Unity games with additional commands and information on startup. "

Comment: @AlpakaJoe yes you can build apps using `unity.exe` ... But you can not run a built app with those parameters (at least not you haven't implemented them by yourself)

Comment: i posted an answer how i solved it today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all your comments, i solved it today:

```
setlocal
cd /d "%~dp0"
Game.exe -logFile ./Logs/output_log.txt
```

this is working fine for me.